# python 2 to python 3 : >=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python-3.6

i have the problem with the following code with the error

> =' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'

```
b = None
if max([a, b]) <= t:
```

I want the code to work in both python 2 and python 3. The above code is working in python 2 because comparison is allowed between NoneType and INT but not allowed in python3,

if max([simil_bank, simil_efx]) <= Tl:

Comment: The meaning of that code is implementation-dependent in Python 2. In CPython, `None` is less than any `int` only because `'None' < 'int'` is true. Another implementation is allowed to treat `None` as greater than some or all other `int` values.

Comment: If you are *assuming* that `None` is always less than an `int`, you should just filter them out right away: `if all(x <= t for x in [a,b] if x is not None)`. `all` will return True given an empty iterable, if there are no non-`None` values in the list.

Comment: set None explicitly to 0 or a small number, for example -sys.maxint+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could provide a `key` function that returns `-inf` when the value is `None`:

```
if max([a, b], key=lambda val: float('-inf') if val is None else val) <= t:
```

Comment: i have set the none type explicitly to 0 for comparison and that works.
thanks